# Need to know if 50 amp break

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image: can I use a 50 amp break to run all what it show in picture. Or can I use a 100 amp panel with a 50 amp break]

1. Want to know 100amp breaker box
   Can be use

Comment: Please add more words to both your title and post body. Neither are clear.

Comment: That is only a 50 amp buss/main , can you feed a 100 amp box yes but the breaker will be 50 or less. I agree with Isherwood we don’t know what you are trying to or want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get a 100 Amp breaker box, but you'll have to check the size of your service wires and either have them upgraded or reduce the 100A breaker to what your service can handle, which may be only 50A depending if they oversized wire.  In the top right you can see the main breaker in your panel is 50A and the busbars are rated for 50A as well.  A 100A panel has 100A busbars, but the breaker can be replaced with a lower rating to correctly match the feed.